# the exact replacement for dictionaryWithObjects: forKeys: in swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I am converting code from objective c to swift, I am unable to find the replacement for `dictionaryWithObjects: forKeys:` anything that I try is not giving the expected output.

I tried `dict.updateValue(values[i]!, forKey: keys[i] as! String )`
inside a for loop, but I realised that there are constant no of elements in keys(26) but for values(20,000) it has many elements. 
So please help me!!
Sorry if I'm wrong, Thanks in Advance.

```
for i in 0..<alphabets.count {  
  in_memory_prediction.updateValue(prediction[i]!, forKey: alphabets[i] as! String) 
}
```

Comment: this is in objc       ***  in_memory_prediction = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:prediction forKeys:alphabets]; ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to update dictionary directly even the value is object

```
var eachKey = alphabets[i] as! String
in_memory_prediction[eachKey] = prediction[i]!
```

Comment: thank you so much!! this is exactly what I wanted.